# Navigator.pushedName does not work. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm currently developing an app on VScode. In my Sign up page I'm using createUserWithEmailAndPassword (firebase authentication), once the sign up button is clicked the email shows in Firebase Authentication, but it does not navigate to the next page where the user can enter their profile information. and if I hot restart or hot reload the project it the app freezes and I have to terminate it for it to work again.

```
SignupButton(
                            text: 'Sign Up',
                            color: kColor,
                            onTap: () async {
                              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                try {
                                  final  user = (await _auth
                                          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                              email: _emailController.text,
                                              password:
                                                  _passwordController.text))
                                      ;
                                      if (user!=null){Navigator.pushNamed(
                                      context, DoctorAccountSetup.id);}
                                  
                                } catch (e) {
                                  print('Error Happened!!!: $e');
                                }
                              }
                            }),
```

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: Registration.id,
      routes: {
          // id = Static String id = 'InitialPage'; for each dart file
        InitialPage.id: (context) => InitialPage(),
        Login.id: (context) => Login(),

        Infopage.id: (context) => Infopage(),
        Registration.id: (context) => Registration(),
        DoctorAccountSetup.id: (context) => DoctorAccountSetup(),
        
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Debug Console]

How can I fix this?

**Edit**

```
SignupButton(
                 text: 'Sign Up',
                 color: kColor,
                 onTap: () {
                 Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/doctorAccountSetup");
                 // if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {} 
                 // when the if statement is commented the navigation works fine. 
               // Might the problem be in the try and catch?
                              
 }),
```

Comment: Please provide the value of `routes` in `MaterialApp(..., routes: ...)`. Also, what is the value of 'DoctorAccountSetup.id`?

Answer (score 0):

since DoctorAccountSetup.Id is the name of your page, try changing it to a string in your main.dart to test things, i.e:
make the route name look like this:

`'/doctorAccountSetup': (context) => DoctorAccountSetup(),`

and use this for naviagtion.

```
if (user!=null){    
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/doctorAccountSetup");
}
```

What happens?

Comment: DoctorAccountSetup.id = String routeName.

Comment: I modified my answer, try that and please updateon what happens.

Comment: I tried using the string, nothing happens same state.

Comment: what happens in your debug console, what is the output?
Also, remove the parenthesis around you auth function. 

`user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _emailController.text,password:_passwordController.text);`

Comment: I/flutter (19999): mail@gmail.com
I/flutter (19999): 12345As!
I/flutter (19999): Validation Ok! Submit!
W/System  (19999): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2 I/System.out(19999): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/flutter (19999): mail@gmail.com
I/flutter (19999): 12345As!

Comment: @salma.m try `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/doctorAccountSetup")`

Comment: I edited the question. I commented out the If statement and navigation works, but i dont think the problemm is in the if statement since the print executes fine, so i guess my problem is in the try and catch statement.

Comment: Move your navigation  outside the try catch block, and return the if statement, it should work, can you confirm?